# Global variable, delay and this

Tags: jquery

I wrote this simple mechanism to add some interactivity and effects to my menu:

```
var $body = $('body');
var $theNav = $('.the-nav-wrapper');
var $theMenuBar = $('.the-menu-bar');
var $menuOpener = $('.menu-opener');

$menuOpener.on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser textAppears');     
   $theNav.toggleClass('open');
   $body.toggleClass('preventScroll');
   $theMenuBar.toggleClass('bringOnTop');
   $(this).toggleText('Menu', 'Close');    
});
```

This works fine.

Along the lines of coding my menu, i decided that i want to add a delay between the toggling of classes `becomeMenuCloser textAppears` so that `becomeMenuCloser` is toggled first and then, after a short delay, `textAppears` is toggled.

I modified the particular line of code responsible for toggling the classes as following:

`$(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser').delay(1300).toggleClass('textAppears');`

*This does not work*. 
It toggles both classes at the same time. Then i tried this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser').promise().done(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('textAppears'); 
});
```

*This also does not work*.
Then i tried this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser');
setTimeout(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('textAppears'); 
}, 610);
```

*This also does not work*, as it the code never goes into the setTimeout and subsequently never toggles the second class.

After trial and error (and some frustration and pondering) i accidentally found that the solution to my problem was to remove `$(this)` and substitute it with the cached variable `$menuOpener`, just like the code below:

```
$(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser')
setTimeout(function() {
  $menuOpener.toggleClass('textAppears'); 
}, 310);
```

This works.

**The questions are:**

**1)** Why was `$(this)` the problem in this case? I really would like to understand the missing clue here.

**2)** I also do not understand why using the `$menuOpener` solves the problem.

**3)** When storing an element as a global variable, should i exclusively use the global variable and omit `$(this)`?

Hey, thanks!

Comment: 1 & 2 - `this` is completely different context than you expect it to be down there, simple as that. Where exactly are you "caching" stuff? Do you mean storing it in a global variable? If so, if you're sure that's the one you're targeting each time and it's correct, you'll make it more "efficient", not visible with naked eye though.

Comment: If you're not completely sure of how `$(this)` works in every context, avoid it unless you're writing code that can't know what object it needs to reference.

Comment: Yes, i meant global variable, i am going to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there are different contexts(this's).

Check the following example:
 [Jsfiddle(click on the div text and check the console)](https://jsfiddle.net/wnx592j1/)

Example 1:
In the first function the first console.log prints

> context 1 id:foo

while the second prints

> context 2 id:undefined

due to context switch(no longer points to the dom element).

```
//example 1
    function context() {
      var div = $("#foo");
      div.on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser');
        console.log("context 1 id:" + this.id);//foo
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("context 2 id:" + this.id);//undefined
          div.toggleClass('textAppears');
        }, 610);
      })
    }
    context();
```

Now in the second example we use the arrow function (`()=>`) to preserve the context and therefore to use the same "this" instance also in the timeout function and so the console prints the correct id both times.

In the first function the first console.log prints

> context 1 id:foo

and the second one the same

> context 2 id:foo

```
//example 2
function context2() {
  var div = $("#foo2");
  div.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser');
    console.log("context 1 id:" + this.id);//foo
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("context 2 id:" + this.id);//foo
      div.toggleClass('textAppears');
    }, 610);
  })
}
context2();
```

Comment: Correct me please if i am wrong.

What you are saying is that as soon as i go into the setTimeout function:

1) the function makes $(this) lose it's context, unless you specify the element again, or you use the arrow function to preserve the context.

Comment: Is this also the reason why chaining functions did not work and toggled the classes at the same time? ex: $(this).toggleClass('becomeMenuCloser').delay(610).toggleClass('textAppears');

Comment: Delay() function only works with animations but you could use the chaining if you use the "duration" parameter in Jquery UI override(https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/). Check here the updated code 
 https://jsfiddle.net/fp6hgreq/

Comment: Thank you :) I am going to wait a little longer for any other answers and then i am going to accept your solution. Cheers